# Emacs 24, Rope rename: "calculating rename changes", then becomes unresponsive

Tags: python, emacs, refactoring, ropemacs

When I use Rope to refactor Python, rename a class name, the minibuffer says "calculating rename changes...", and the machine becomes slow, even not response.

Did I miss any configs, or is it a bug of Emacs 24/Rope?

My configs:

```
(require 'pymacs)
(autoload 'pymacs-apply "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-call "pymacs")
(autoload 'pymacs-eval "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-exec "pymacs" nil t)
(autoload 'pymacs-load "pymacs" nil t)
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")
;;(pymacs-load "pysmell.emacshelper" "pysmell-")
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)
```

Comment: solved: i create the rope-prj in $HOME. do NOT do this.

Answer (score 0):

Press **ctrl+x,p,o** or **:RopeOpenProject** to make force rope create .ropeproject in current dir.

if you don't have .ropeproject

rope will search in your home directory, that was why the machine becomes slow, even not response.

**see : https://github.com/klen/python-mode#rope-completion-is-very-slow**

Answer (score 0):

As @user1627021 mentioned, refactoring using rope can be slow sometimes and it's frustrating to use ropemacs sometimes because it blocks Emacs even when the actual work is done in Python process.  There is another rope plugin for Emacs called [traad](https://github.com/abingham/traad).  Unlike ropemacs, it does not block during refactoring.  Probably it's worth a try if you work on large code base.